# Getting a compile error ('Object Required) even though I've made all the necessary declarations and set my variables

Tags: vba, loops

I'm applying the trim function to my column (B) via a simple loop. Here is my code (I've tried with and without option explicit- get the same error regardless):

I don't understand why I'm getting an object required error. There are no blank cells in the column.

```
Sub Trim()
Dim Cell As Long, SalesWs As Worksheet, LastRow As Long, Rng As Range

Set SalesWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales")
Set LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set Rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sales").Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
 For Each Cell In Range("Rng")

        Cell.Value = Trim(Cell.Value)

     
        
    Next Cell
    
    
Exit Sub

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Accidentally pasted it from another module.

Comment: `LastRow` is a `Long` which is not an object so you don't use `Set`. Remove the word `Set`. And declare `Cell` as `Range` instead of `Long`

Comment: `For Each Cell In Rng`

Comment: Thanks Raymond, Made that change but now i'm getting For this error:  Each control variable must be Variant or Object. There are no strings in this columns (just ints)- so it makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Lysander2001 It will be helpful if you can update the code in the question (I assume you have incorporated braX's comment too). Note: unless you include `@` infront of the user you want to ping, we will not receive any notification.

Comment: @Lysander2001 Please change your `Sub` name, `Trim` is an existing function.

Comment: And use `Dim Cell As Range` or `Dim Cell`...